# \hfill inside a tabular environment doesn't flush right

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, colortbl

When I put an `\hfill` in a tabular row colored using the `colortbl` package, the coloring does not extend to what I would expect the end of the row to be.

For example, the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
  \rowcolor{black}\textcolor{white}{Sample Text}\\
  \rowcolor{black}\hfill\textcolor{white}{More Text}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image]

I would expect it to produce something like this:

[image]

I'm guessing that the problem is that using `\hfill` is somehow changing the length of the line. Is that the case? And, if not, why does the length of the coloring change when I use `\hfill`?

Comment: LaTeX centers the material in a `c` column internally by inserting `\hfill` on either side of the material in a cell. Your setup thus leads to `\hfill\hfill <material> \hfill`, and `<material>` is therefore *not* shoved all the way to the right. To really shove the material to the right, use `\multicolumn{1}{r}{<material>}` -- `\multicolumn{1}{...}{...}` explicitly overrides the cell's definition.

Comment: Use `l` instead of `c` and your trick should work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `\hspace{0pt plus 1filll}` that would override the `\hfill` at the end of the cell, but this would confuse the coloring as the example shows. Better stating right alignment with `\multicolumn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\hfilll{\hspace{0pt plus 1filll}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
Sample Text\\
\hfilll More Text\\
\rowcolor{black}\textcolor{white}{Sample Text}\\
\rowcolor{black}\hfilll\textcolor{white}{More Text}\\
\rowcolor{black}\textcolor{white}{Sample Text}\\
\rowcolor{black}\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textcolor{white}{More Text}}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Keep in mind that the reverse would require *two* glues (one infinite and the other zero) because a glue at the end of the cell is removed (by `\unskip`).

[image]